How to prove that when applying the separating axis theorem to convex 3D polyhedra, I only need to consider the face and edge-edge normals
So when checking to see if two convex 3D polyhedra are colliding, it is known that you only have to consider separation along the outward face normals and the normals obtained by crossing the edges of the shapes with eachother. I was wondering, how can I prove that considering just these axes is sufficient in assessing whether a separating axis exists?
I think I get the intuitive explanation that in order to have the shapes collide, they either collide through a face or through an edge-to-edge collision so it sort of makes sense that you only need to consider the normals corresponding to these collision cases, but I would like an actual rigorous proof that these axes are sufficient.
I think I can get from this post:
Proof of Separating Axis Theorem for polygons
that the minimum separating vector between the convex polyhedra $A$ and $B$ must be normal to a face/bounding-hyperplane of the Minkowski sum $M=A+(-B)$, but how would I tie this to the normals and edges of A and B for the 3D case? Can I try to prove something like that the face normals of $M$ are given by the normals of the faces and edge-edge cross products of $A$ and $B$?
